# TransformationFailedException after PHP update 5.6.26 to 5.6.27

Tags: php, symfony

An application on a shared host now yields a

> ...datefmt_create: no such time zone: 'America/Los_Angeles'

error when a user attempts to access a form with a date field.  The complete message is:

> Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException:
>   "Unable to transform value for property path "contactDate":
>   datefmt_create: no such time zone: 'America/Los_Angeles':
>   U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR" at
>   /www3.projectmana.org/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php
>   line 1149

There have been no other changes to the site in weeks.

The default timezone via `phpinfo()` is `America/Los_Angeles`

Any rational explanations/fix for this? There is a sandbox of the site on the same server that demonstrates the same error.  The error does not occur on my development PHP 7 system.

#### Edit:

I've replaced the Symfony 2.8 installation with (tested) 3.1.5 - similar behavior.  The error now:

> An Error Occurred! Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\InvalidOptionsException:
>   "datefmt_create: no such time zone: 'America/Los_Angeles':
>   U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR" at
>   /www3.projectmana.org/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php
>   line 88

using the following simplified code:

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/datecheck")
 */
public function dateCheckAction()
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('dueDate', DateType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task'))
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('Default/datecheck.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

template:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

#### Edit #2:

When I look at the application's error rather than that from the simple code above, I see:

> An Error Occurred! Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException:
>   "Unable to transform value for property path "contactDate":
>   datefmt_create: no such time zone: 'America/Los_Angeles':
>   U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR" at
>   /www3.projectmana.org/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php
>   line 1095

The code from Form.php around that line:

```
try {
    foreach ($this->config->getViewTransformers() as $transformer) {
        $value = $transformer->transform($value);
    }
} catch (TransformationFailedException $exception) {
    throw new TransformationFailedException(
        'Unable to transform value for property path "'.$this->getPropertyPath().'": '.$exception->getMessage(),
        $exception->getCode(),
        $exception
    );
}
```

The result of a `var_dump($transformer)` when that is included in the Exception is

```
object(Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer)#1128 (6) { ["dateFormat":"Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer":private]=> int(2) ["timeFormat":"Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer":private]=> int(-1) ["pattern":"Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer":private]=> string(5) "M/d/y" ["calendar":"Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer":private]=> int(1) ["inputTimezone":protected]=> string(19) "America/Los_Angeles"
```

Not sure what to do with this info.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a PHP problem; it sounds more like your timezone (zoneinfo) file got corrupted somehow?

Comment: @jhaagsma I'll pass this along to the host; I have no control over the server.  Thanks.

Comment: @jhaagsma The host reports the zoneinfo file is fine and php scripts with date functions perform properly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try Example 1A from the [PHP DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() help page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php)?

```
<?php
$timezone_identifiers = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
foreach ($timezone_identifiers as $id) {
    echo "$id\n";
}
?>
```

This will output all the timezones... and if your timezone is in the list, then it's something else.

Comment: Done.  `America/Los_Angeles` appears in the output.

Comment: Hmm. Not that then. I'm not totally familiar with Symfony, but I'd take a peek at the relevant line, and see what it's trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

The solution but not yet an answer will be for the webmaster of the shared host to figure out why IntlDateFormatter returns null.  When the host runs

```
<?php
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('en', null, null);

echo 'timezone_id of the formatter is : ' . $fmt->getTimezoneId();
```

The response is

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimezoneId() on null

When it should be

> timezone_id of the formatter is : America/Los_Angeles

The webmaster has already recompiled both PECL-intl and ICU but it didn't seem to change anything.