# Force use of Symfony intl component?

Tags: php, symfony

On a shared host, after a PHP upgrade from 5.26 to 5.27, IntlDateFormatter fails to recognize the `default.timezone`.  (See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186790/transformationfailedexception-after-php-update-5-6-26-to-5-6-27/40219654#40219654).) A simple experiment:

```
<?php
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('en', null, null);

echo 'timezone_id of the formatter is : ' . $fmt->getTimezoneId();
```

on the host yields:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimezoneId() on null...

If it's possible to force the use of Symfony's `intl` I can test whether the timezone is properly returned and the application will again function. What I need to do is to force the use of Symfony's `intl` in a Symfony application.  I'm not sufficiently clever to figure out how to get its Form components to use it rather than the already installed PHP intl extension.

Comment: instead of pick `IntlDateFormatter` from the global space just use symfony's `Symfony\Component\Intl\DateFormatter\IntlDateFormatter`

Comment: @Federkun Thanks. What I need to do is to force the use of Symfony's `intl` in a Symfony application.  I'm not sufficiently clever to figure out how to get its Form components to use it rather than the already installed PHP intl extension.  I'll edit my question to make this clear.